# What does the PEP's status and structure mean?

Tags: python, operator-keyword, pep

What is the PEP status' structure and mean?

These days, I try to write a python2.7 interpreter.

But, I don't know why comparison operator <> arise in python 2.7. (It was not in python 3.0)
Figure out it was in the PEP401.
The official declarations is for future compatibility (import from **future** or somewhat)

Something confusing me is that the status was `April Fool!`

April Fool?

Ref:

1. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0401/
2. http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2009-April/1202030.html

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/April_Fools%27_Day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked PEP is, as the status suggests, an April Fool's joke; it is not a real PEP.

There is no distinct `<>` operator; however, in Python 2, the interpreter will read `<>` as a synonym for `!=`. In Python 3, `<>` is a syntax error.

Comment: Notes: The PEP's number is 401, i.e. 4/01 or April 1st (April Fools' Day); the PEP states that GvR is stepping down, which makes no sense and wouldn't be announced via a PEP anyway; the new title given to him would be pronounced "bedevil" and is thus obviously facetious (not to mention the bit about climbing Mount Everest); claims that CPython will not support 2.7 (patently false); there are in-jokes about the Parrot virtual machine and the "non-existent" Python Secret Underground (possibly a throw-back to "TINC" on USENET).

Comment: It's a little bit hard for a Chinese to understand well. :)